# gnuplot point color wrong

Tags: colors, gnuplot, point

In this example, the point color(blue) of the 3. plot differs from the test output(green) - why is that? (my default terminal is aqua, but it is the same with e.g. png)

```
plot [0:4]\
     '-' title 'pt1' with points pt 1,\
     2*x title 'lt1' with lines  lt 1,\
     '-' title 'pt2' with points pt 2,\
     3*x title 'lt2' with lines  lt 2
     1  1
     2  5
     end
     1  3
     3  7
     end
```

by changing the order of the plots, the color changes:

```
plot [0:4]\
     '-' title 'pt1' with points pt 1,\
     '-' title 'pt2' with points pt 2,\
     2*x title 'lt1' with lines  lt 1,\
     3*x title 'lt2' with lines  lt 2
     1  1
     2  5
     end
     1  3
     3  7
     end
```

Comment: Why does your code look like some kind of wierd gun? Are you trying to integrate it with the shell or something? You can try at firearms.SE, if so.

Comment: I can reproduce your findings and it sure does look like a bug to me. Maybe you want to report it at the development site [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/).

Comment: Ok - thanks. I will report a bug, unless someone solves the mystery soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User sfeam on SourceForge provides the answer:

> point type does not control color. It is the third plot, and you have
>   not instructed otherwise, so it gets the color of linetype 3 (blue).

Apparently the color of lines plot is set by the number of previous lines
plots, while the color of points plot is set by the number of all previous
plots.
Both can be controlled by linecolor or lc.